# No update Database (Only Read / Write)

Tags: mysql, mongodb, bigdata, database, nosql

We are designing a bank grade application with tons of transactional data.  One of the requirements is that all transactional data should only be read and write with no update possible.  We can control updates from the application level but the requirements are that even if someone has DB or root level access, they can not update the current records.

Do you know any database or system that can offer such feature?  Basically once a record is created, it can not be deleted or updated in any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases provide user based privilages, I would take mysql [privilages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html) example you just need to create two users for your app, and grant the write user permissions for INSERT. The read user can be granted the permissions for SELECT. Do not grant any  permission for UPDATE OR DELETE statement.